# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' (C:\Users\Kalyan Mohanty\Documents\GitHub\Django\rek\calc\urls.py)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am learning Django but in the way of building my first I am facing this issue.

**ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' (C:\Users\Kalyan Mohanty\Documents\GitHub\Django\rek\calc\urls.py)**

**Under my app 'calc' folder**

**urls.py**

`from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlspatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home')
    ]`

**views.py**

`from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import admin`

`def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')`

**rek folder**
**urls.py**

`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include`

`urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`

**structure**

`-calc (folder)`

```
 `-__pycache__ (folder)`

 `-migrations (folder)`

 `-__init__`

 `-admin.py`

 `-apps.py`

 `-models.py`

 `-test.py`

 `-urls.py`

 `-views.py`
```

`-rek (folder)`

```
 `-__pycache__`

 `-__init__`

 `-settings.py`

 `-urls.py`

 `-wsgi.py`
```

`db.sqlite3`

`manage.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use import views.This works for me

Comment: I have i tried it before . But while running the server I am getting following error.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'`

Comment: If I am using `from . import views` . while running server I am getting error as `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'calc.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Kalyan Mohanty\\Documents\\GitHub\\Django\\rek\\calc\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`